# Load JSON Data into Highcharts Drilldown map Dynamicly

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, highcharts, highmaps

I use PHP to generate JSON files for my main US map and for the drill down maps. I would like to incorporate both data points into the map using the following example:

[Highcharts Map Drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-drilldown/)

Someone on the Highcharts forum suggested this:

> The simple idea is to not use drilldown, but to develop workaround by
>   adding and removing series - those calls can be using ajax calls, so
>   data will be included asynchronously.

I was able to incorporate the main map data using the following code:

**main.js Code that gets called on my page**

```
function create_chart() {
        $.getJSON('/includes/data/states.json', function(data) {
                $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
                        series: [{
                            name: 'States',
                            data: data,
                            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
                            joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
                            type: 'map',
                        }],
                        });
                });
        }
        $(document).ready(create_chart);
```

**Sample of the main map data (states.json)**

```
[
    {
        "drilldown": "ak",
        "code": "us-ak",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "drilldown": "al",
        "code": "us-al",
        "value": "22"
    },
    {
        "drilldown": "ar",
        "code": "us-ar",
        "value": "7"
    },
...
]
```

I get bugged down on including the data from my second JSON file which holds the drilldown items. Here is the format:

**Sample of drilldow data (counties.json)**

```
[
    {
        "code": "us-de-005",
        "name": "Sussex County, DE",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "code": "us-al-03",
        "name": "Baldwin County, AL",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "code": "us-al-39",
        "name": "Covington County, AL",
        "value": "2"
    },
...
]
```

I assume that I need to adjust the following line in the example that currently set to dummy random data:

**Lines 46-51**

```
                    data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);
                    // Set a non-random bogus value
                    $.each(data, function (i) {
                        this.value = i;
                    });
```

Any ideas on how I can insert my json data instead of bogus data?

Comment: Maybe @Paweł Fus can help

Comment: Or @Sebastian Bochan could pitch in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have this part of the code:

```
$.getScript('http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', function () {

                        var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]); // namespace

                        // Set a non-random bogus value
                        $.each(data, function (i) {
                            this.value = i;
                        });
                        ...
 });
```

Which loads map. Now, instead of setting data, make another AJAX call:

```
$.getScript('http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', function () {

                        data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);

                        // get data:
                        $.getJSON("myURL?mapkey=" + mapKey, function(data_2) { 
                            // assign your data points to the series
                            var data = []; 
                            ...

                            // update chart in the callback:

                            // Hide loading and add series
                            chart.hideLoading();
                            clearTimeout(fail);
                            chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                                name: e.point.name,
                                joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
                                type: 'map',
                                data: data,
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    format: '{point.name}'
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        ...
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the import both data files and it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/q6rw4581/. Line 6 - US map data and line 39 for drilldown.

Comment: Two things you need to fix: 
**a)** AJAX is asynchronous, when adding series as drilldown, do it in the callback. 
**b)** cross-origin won't allow you to load data in the jsFiddle

Comment: not really sure what a) means in terms of code, could you elaborate? On point b)... I am aware of that. I have everything on my Cloud9 project but since its private I pasted the code to jsF for you to look at.

Comment: a) Well, you just need to read about AJAX, even on the jQuery page - it's to long to explain in the comment. b) Ok.

Comment: I did some more digging and I understand the basics of this. I even tried the example listed under custom data processing but still doesn't work. Are there actual code snippets out there that can give me an example of what I am trying to do. Been googling for days now.

Comment: Thanks again. You are truly the to go to person from anything highcharts!

Comment: There is one bug in my answer - about data declaration (the same name as above). Anyway, it's not really connected to the Highcharts ;)